# Internet Explorer 9 uneven letter spacing

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I am installing my new PC with Windows 7 Home Premium. Explorer 9 displays text funnily on my Samsung 27-inch monitor: some (apparently random) letters are separated by larger spaces than they should. E.g. in the attached picture, the word Fish appears as Fis h. Any idea why that could be? - It happens only in Explorer.

[image]

Comment: hmm, Your picture shows it Kerned incorrectly on my monitor too :-) There are big stinks about clear type (or not) and text rendering over at MSes forums. Do a Quick test and select your own font in internet options General tab, Fonts , then in accessability select to Ignore the font on the web page. We also used to Stop all downloading of new fonts in advanced, but they changed that some to allowing fonts in as temps.  It has to be some combination of the new font piles, and the IE rendering methods.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks. I have done all the adjustments you suggest. As for Cleartype, I have disabled it from the moment I got the PC last Saturday. The irregular spacing is still here, even after a few restarts. What's more, the exaggerated spaces occur in the same exact spots in the text; e.g. if I return to the Wikipedia "Fish" page (pictured in the link of my original post), I still get the same problems in the same words.

The problem does not occur in other browsers.

In case anyone has the time to look at it, here is my Belarc computer profile: http://bit.ly/MyPcBlC  . Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish Does not have that problem in IE8 here either. One more thing you can mess with. in Internet Options Advanced, switch the Graphics render method , should be the first item in advanced. and compatability mode, the  "Broken page" icon around the address bar.

Comment: Now I am in IE9 and do not see that occuring here 64bit or 32bit. 2 more things, Text size and zooming. including the main text size DPI settings in display.  So far I cannot even get the bug to show up, no mater what I changed.  . .
Do you have all your Grafic cards drivers installed yet?

Answer (score 1):

@Psycogeek many thanks: the solution was indeed to turn the compatibility mode ON for all websites! Does not make much sense; but that's the way it is...